# git flow - how to start working on existing feature branch

Tags: git, git-flow

I would like to start working on another developer's feature branch (we use git and git flow).
AFAIK The branch has been published (pushed). How can I get it to my local repository?

I tried:

```
git flow feature pull origin/XXXXXX-1003b

fatal: 'origin/XXXXXX-1003b' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Failed to pull from remote 'origin/XXXXXX-1003b'.
```

And:

```
git flow feature pull XXXXXX-1003b

fatal: 'XXXXXX-1003b' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Failed to pull from remote 'XXXXXX-1003b'.
```

Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### git flow feature track

To track an existing feature branch on a remote, use `feature track`:

```
git flow feature track xxxxxx-1003b
```

Alternatively just do it "the normal way":

```
git fetch origin
git branch -a # list all branches
git checkout feature/xxxxxx-1003b
```

I.e. update the remote origin, and then checkout the branch corresponding to your colleague's branch.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have the branch inside your repo, and you want to get it, you have to use `git-flow track`. This should work:

```
git flow feature track XXXXXX-1003b
```

Comment: What does `-1003b` mean? I saw that in another answer and thought it was just a random alphanumeric, but they're identical, so does it have some significance?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the feature/branch name(1):

```
git flow feature track featurename
```

(1) Could be a new git flow feature, I respond to an old question.